# Create a geom_bar with empty bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

```
muscle <- 
  c("4", "4", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", NA,  "3", "4", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3")

label_barchart <- c("0" = "Very Unsatisfied",
                    "1" = "Unsatisfied",
                    "2" = "Neutral",
                    "3" = "Satisfied",
                    "4" = "Very Satisfied")

dataset <- data.frame(muscle)

ggplot(data = dataset) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = muscle)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = label_barchart)
```

I have a dataset which looks like the following, and I want to create a bar graph.

However, hypothetically all values from 0 to 4 should exist. 0 means "Very unsatisfied, 1 means "Satisfied", 2 means "Neutral", 3 means "Satisfied" and 4 means "Very satisfied".

I would like the bar chart to show that no one chose 0 - 2 (i.e. have 3 non-existing boxes on the left). This has been a bit tricky because "0", "1", "2" are not existing in the dataset.

I also want to not include the NA data entry without manipulating the dataset.

This is how it looks like currently:

[image]

Comment: You could add `limits = as.character(0:4)` as argument to the `scale_x_discrete()` call.

Comment: @teunbrand Perfect! Care to post that as an answer?